# Disable blocks for certain pages

Tags: 8

How can I disable blocks (e.g., the menu block or the search block) from a custom module?

Concretely I have an access to my clients managed by a custom module, and I don't want anything appears on their access page except my company's logo.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to install another module to achieve this you might want to disable blocks in `hook_preprocess_page` similar to this

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if ( /* custom logic */ ) {
    unset($vars['page']['REGION-NAME']['BLOCK-MACHINE-NAME']);   
  }  
}
```

It can certainly be used in your THEMENAME.theme file but I believe it can be used in a module as well

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the visibility of many blocks at the same time, this module would be perfect:

https://www.drupal.org/project/block_visibility_groups

> Block Visibility Groups allows the site administrator to easily manage
>   complex visibility settings that apply to any block placed in a
>   visibility group. The visibility settings for all blocks in the group
>   can be edited on one administration form.
>
> This modules works in conjunction with the Drupal 8 core's block
>   administration system. It is a simpler alternative to modules like
>   Panels.

Even you want to code this yourself, you can use this module as a starting point. The author of this module has a 2 hour video how this code was built.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to specify pages in visibility option field in block settings. Or try to use https://www.drupal.org/project/extended_block_visibility if you need specific access rules which placed in custom module

Comment: I don't see a Drupal 8 version of that module...

Comment: Hello Smile,
Thanks for the response, but I would prefer to pilot this from my custom module. And when I disable/ enable my custom module the blocks are directly arranged.
Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've used hook_block_view() to do something like this.
I defined conditions for my block to appear in the function.
My block was a form, so I could assign $blocks['content'] to a drupal_get_form() call, and return my $blocks if my conditions were met.